# 'For' command and filling excel table with pandas by doing web-scrabbing

Tags: excel, pandas, web-scraping

With selenium library, I can open and read some information from a website, but while transferring these data read to an excel table, I can't fill all table with 'for command' because at the end of 'for command' and after saving data frame as 'csv', I see, for the only last i number, the data was put in processed, for other 'i's, filling the table was skipped. I don't know the reason for that.

How can I fill table for all i numbers?

My script is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

inpExcelFile = 'sites of svbilgi kizilirmak.csv'
websites = pd.read_csv(inpExcelFile)
#csvfile can be downloaded from 'https://www.evernote.com/shard/s355/sh/3ba4c779-803c-4f5a-b402-a30ec973c48e/75f2c9aea94454e1'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'D:\chromedriver.exe')

for i in range(1,3): 
    driver.get(str(websites['sitelist'][i]))
    code_and_name=driver.find_element_by_id("Span1").text
    approximate_elevation = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='Table3']/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]").text
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['code_and_name', 'approximate_elevation']
    df.at[i,'code_and_name']= str(code_and_name)
    df.at[i,'approximate_elevation']= str(approximate_elevation)

df.to_csv('observed_data_list.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-9')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I positioned "df = pd.Dataframe" inside for command. I just put it outside and place into just before for command, then the issue was solved.